# How to handle reactor-netty terminating a request in spring-webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

We have a `spring-webflux` application running on `spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE` and `reactor-netty:jar:0.8.8.RELEASE`. When a reactive client goes away (k8s pod killed or the client subscription is disposed off) before the request is completed, we see the server simply stops processing the request and no more application logs related to that request are seen. However, `reactive-netty` prints a trace log indicating that the channel is inactive and will be terminated.

Is there anything we can do to handle this termination gracefully? We would ideally like to respond to a cancellation signal from reactor.

```
2020-03-18T16:46:40.372Z TRACE --- [reactor-http-epoll-2] r.n.c.ChannelOperations : [id: 0x4cad974b, L:/<SERVER_IP_ADDRESS>:8080 ! R:/<SOME_OTHER_IP_ADDRESS>:55436] Disposing ChannelOperation from a channel
java.lang.Exception: ChannelOperation terminal stack
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:391)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundClose(ChannelOperations.java:360)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelInactive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:72)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:236)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:420)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:393)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:236)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1416)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:912)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:816)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:331)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: See this enhancement request https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1022 you can apply the current solution though we need to enhance the feature

Comment: Hi @VioletaGeorgieva, the issue you linked to seems to be related to when the server dies unexpectedly, which is different from our issue where the client dies unexpectedly.

Comment: Also, the graceful handling of termination we desire is limited to one request connection only (which is "cancelled" by the client) as opposed to the one in your issue where the server itself is shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

The `doOnCancel` operator allows for a callback to be provided when a subscription is cancelled. This is different from the `doOnEach` operator which is run only when the subscription completes or errors out.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnCancel-java.lang.Runnable-